# MySql - Using concat with date columns

Tags: mysql, concatenation

When i try to concat to date columns in my table like so:

```
CONCAT(`date_from`,' - ',`date_to`) AS `period`
```

I get a wierd result, something like this:

```
323031322d30312d303120323031322d30312d3031
```

But if i change the type of the column from DATE to VARCHAR the result is correct.

Why can't I concat date columns?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to change date type to CHAR using [CAST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) function like

```
CONCAT(CAST(`date_from` AS CHAR),' - ',CAST(`date_to` AS CHAR)) AS `period`
```

Comment: Why not use `DATE_FORMAT` there? I believe it'll give a result that will not change depending on the caller's connection setting...

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
SELECT CAST(CONCAT(`date_from`,' - ',`date_to`)
 AS CHAR) FROM `some_table` WHERE 1
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9idr.png)**try this one...**

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(date) FROM TABLE group by id
```

Comment: Can you share an explanation about your solution?

Comment: group concat(date) will gives the results as (23-08-2018,24-08-2018,....)all the date in the table will get concat, to get the result by group...use group by to group the concat date.